Making sense of constant scalar curvature metric horns
Suppose we have a compact oriented surface $S$ and we remove a point $p$ on it. We could consider a neighboorhood $U$ of the puncture $p$, so that the points in this neighboorhood are described by coordinates $(r,y)$, for which $p$ corresponds precisely to $r=0$ (polar coordinates centered at $p$). For example, one could choose a smooth metric on $S$ and define $r$ to be the distance in that metric with respect to $p$, and $U$ the set of points that are at distance e.g. smaller than $\epsilon$ to $p$.
Now we construct another metric by setting it to be $g_1=dr^2+r^2dy^2$ in $U$ and choosing a compatible extension to $S\setminus U$ so that the total metric is e.g. smooth on $S\setminus \{p\}$. We call that a conic metric.
Because the scalar curvature of the metric $g_1$ vanishes, we can hope to find a conic metric on $S\setminus \{p\}$ with vanishing (constant) scalar curvature. If we rather wanted e.g. constant positive scalar curvature, we could have chosen $g_1=dr^2+a\sin^2(br) dy^2$ for certain constants $a,b>0$, depending on which value we want for the metric (not important for the question).
I wanted to test if such an idea would extend to the context of metric horns. With that I mean, in the simplest case, a metric around $p$ of the form $g_\alpha=dr^2+r^{2\alpha}dy^2$, where $\alpha>1$ (I could analogously "imitate" the conic metrics with non-vanishing curvature).
However, when I compute the scalar curvature of such a metric, I get $2\alpha(1-\alpha)r^{-2}$. This, of course, gives back the result for cones when $\alpha=1$. So I turn to look within the conformal class of $g_\alpha$, e.g. at metrics of the form $e^{2\phi}g_\alpha$, to see if there is a metric of constant scalar curvature there. Their scalar curvature then takes the form $$e^{-2\phi}(2\Delta_{g_\alpha}(\phi)+scal_{g_\alpha})$$ where the Laplace-Beltrami operator for the original metric horn appears.
Now here, I could set this expression to equal a constant and then try to solve for $\phi$. In the process of conformally transforming the metric I do not want to "kill" the horn, and therefore there should be a restriction on the $\phi$ that should be allowed. I suspect such a restriction should be of Hölder type, e.g. $\phi$ is Hölder, where its differentiability is adapted to the metric, like in Section 4.1 here but swapping $r\partial_r$ with $r^\alpha\partial_r$.
I found a lot of literature on similar questions, mostly for cones, but I did not manage to derive a positive or negative answer to my question from them: is it possible to have constant curvature in a metric horn, e.g. in a metric "Hölder-conformal" to $g_\alpha$? What is only relevant is that the metric near the puncture asymptotically behaves like $g_\alpha$, not necessarily being equal or conformal to it in the whole of $U$. Analytically, I am trying to solve the following equation for $\phi$ Hölder (but perhaps Hölder is not a good geometrical restriction):
\begin{equation}
\Delta_{g_\alpha}(\phi)-ce^{2\phi}=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{r^2}
\end{equation}
for a fixed $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\phi=\phi(r,y)$ in $0<r<\epsilon$.
